Media3 API JavaScript Android
How would one go about using MediaSession (part of the Media3 API) in a Nativescript android app? Currently, all the examples I've seen are in Kotlin or Java.
I'd like to convert this to either JavaScript or TypeScript.
override fun onCreate() {
  super.onCreate()

  val likeButton = CommandButton.Builder()
    .setDisplayName("Like")
    .setIconResId(R.drawable.like_icon)
    .setSessionCommand(SessionCommand(SessionCommand.COMMAND_CODE_SESSION_SET_RATING))
    .build()
  val favoriteButton = CommandButton.Builder()
    .setDisplayName("Save to favorites")
    .setIconResId(R.drawable.favorite_icon)
    .setSessionCommand(SessionCommand(SAVE_TO_FAVORITES, Bundle()))
    .build()

  session =
    MediaSession.Builder(this, player)
      .setCallback(CustomMediaSessionCallback())
      .setCustomLayout(ImmutableList.of(likeButton, favoriteButton))
      .build()
}


You should clarify if this is for mobile browser or hybrid mobile app.
